# Select 5 random rows per Distinct value

Tags: sql-server, random, distinct

I have a raw table:

[Raw Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5ROT.png)
[image]

I want to write a query that will return 5 random [Case Number] values for each [Case Owner]. If the [Case Owner] has less than 5 cases such as Casper or Mark, the query should return all cases for those agents. An example desired output would be:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Wzg.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will give you the desired output.

```
 SELECT [Case Owner],[Case Number] FROM
 (
  SELECT [Case Owner],[Case Number], 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Case Owner] ORDER BY NEWID()) RN
  FROM [Your_Table]
 )T
 WHERE T.RN < 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select randomly, give a row number based on the order of the random number and group by `case owner` and then select the rows having row number from 1 to 5.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [case owner]
        order by ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 100
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [case owner], [case number] 
from cte
where [rn] < 6;
```